# MySQL to MariaDB migration on IBM i connected to DB2 with IBMDB2I storage engine and RPG programs

Tags: mysql, mariadb, db2, ibm-midrange

we are in the process of migrating MySQL to MariaDB database on IBM i (AS400) server, but the problem is that MySQL DB has some databases connected to DB2 with DB2 storage engine so the migration will affect programs RPGs that need recompilation. How can we migrate databases with automatic RPG recompilation?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built into the system that will provide automatic recompilation.

There's various commercial tools that attempt to provide such functionality.

I'm not familiar with the MySQL to MariaDb migration on IBM i, what's causing the tables to change and thus the need to recompile the RPG Programs?  Are you using the Zend DBi repackage of MariaDb?  From the [docs](https://help.zend.com/zend/zenddbi/Content/About.htm),

> Zend DBi is based on MariaDB with care and support for IBMi. It is a
> drop-in replacement for MySQL on many systems.

It doesn't appear the the standard distro of MariaDb supports the old [IBMDB2I storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/ibmdb2i-storage-engine/)

Comment: Yes it's Zend DBI based on MariaDB and has support for IBMDB2I

Comment: We need to recompile RPG because some DBs in MySQL are connected to DB2 with IMBDB2I storage engine so when we migrate to ZendDBI we need to dump and later DROP DBs in MySQL and recreate DBs in ZendDBI with DB2 storage engine.

Comment: IMBDB2?  You mean IBMDB2I?  Zend DBi still uses [it](https://help.zend.com/zend/zenddbi/Content/DB2i%20Storage%20Engine.htm) I'd suggest talking to Zend....

Comment: Yes, IBMDB2I i have no problems wirh it, my problem is migration and RPG recompilation